# How can I redirect to an external url using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to redirect to an external url from a relative url passed as href of an a tag in html:
I have the following xml code

```
  <links>
     <link id="faq" text="F.A.Q." url="en/faq/" external="true" />
     <link id="contactUs" text="Contacts" url="en/company/contacts/" external="true" />
     <link id="termsAndConditions" text="Terms and Conditions" url="en/terms/" external="true" />
  </links>
```

and the following xslt transformation to get the HTML:

```
            <a href="{@url}" title="{@text}" class="page__footer__nav__link">
                <xsl:if test="@external = 'true'">
                   <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                 <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
            </a>
```

the HTML must be something like this:

```
<a href="domain/en/faq" target="_blank" />
```

for the three anchor tags

Comment: Please post a complete XSLT stylesheet, together with the XHTML code you expect as a result.

Comment: And where does `domain` come from? Please post complete code.

Comment: domain is a webpage is just an example but domain will be something like www.xxxxxx.xx

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But where does this domain URL string come from? Will it always be the same? Is it in the input XML? Do you supply it to the transformation as a parameter?

Comment: yes it will always be the same, the input XML has just the relative URL that i want to append to the domain URL

Comment: See my answer. It seems that you have not reacted to answers to previous questions of yours, e.g. there are several answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027262/how-can-i-center-a-button-inside-a-div-vertically) - please accept one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the domain string in a parameter and use `concat()` to produce the result URL.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="domain" select="'www.example.com/'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/links">
      <hmtl>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="link">
        <a href="{concat($domain,@url)}" title="{@text}" class="page__footer__nav__link">
            <xsl:if test="@external = 'true'">
                <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<hmtl>
   <a href="www.example.com/en/faq/" title="F.A.Q." class="page__footer__nav__link" target="_blank">F.A.Q.</a>
   <a href="www.example.com/en/company/contacts/" title="Contacts" class="page__footer__nav__link" target="_blank">Contacts</a>
   <a href="www.example.com/en/terms/" title="Terms and Conditions" class="page__footer__nav__link" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a>  
</hmtl>
```